# Raspberri Pi unreachable

Tags: networking, hdmi, ubuntu, pi-4

I am totally new to the forum, linux and Rasperry Pi, which is not the best baseline, I know. I bought some Raspberry's (4B) and made two bootable SD cards. I don't like the interface of Raspbian, so I installed Ubuntu and Ubuntu Mate. The problem now is that they won't connect with my TV via HDMI and are not visible in the network via LAN. So I don't see any possibility to communicate with the Pi. Have I just forgotten to setup something or is there an easy solution for this problem? (To flash the images I used Win32 Disk imager for the Ubuntu.iso and Etcher for the Ubuntu Mate.img)

I sincerely hope that there is someone who can help me.

Comment: Given you are new to Linux and the Raspberry Pi I don't see how you decided Ubuntu was a better choice than Raspbian.  I suggest you go back to Raspbian until you are more familiar with Linux and the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @joan It is just about the Interface. I have used Raspbian before in school cause we didn't have enough Windows PCs. So I'd prefere an Ubuntu, but if there is no other solution I must change, right.

Comment: I'm sure there is a solution to getting Ubuntu working with your TV and network, I just don't know what it is. Someone else will know.

Comment: Joan has a very good point in that if you are looking for help, most Pi users use Raspbian.  I *think* the issue with Ubuntu is there is not Pi 4 ready image (if wherever you got it from doesn't explicitly say it is ok for Pi 4, assume it is not).  You should edit into the question what the red and green LEDs do when you try to boot.  I'll guess the green light either never comes on, or comes on and stays on, meaning the SD card is not recognized at all (check and see if it does the same thing with no card in).

Comment: @goldilocks Thank you very much. It' true that there is a Version of Ubuntu Mate for the Pi, but not for Pi 4

Comment: You know you are not bound to using the default DE.  Raspbian is really a customized Debian, so GNOME, KDE, Cinnamon, MATE etc. are available.  Your best bet is probably to install Raspbian lite (the version with no GUI), and find a guide somewhere about installing MATE on Debian.  It will be exactly the same.   You could also ask here about that.  You can have multiple DEs installed, so you could do this from the standard full version (you can actually run different ones at the same time and switch between them with a keystroke).  Just avoid NOOBS.

Comment: @user12053478, Well, my first impression with Rpi 1, 2 raspbian wheezy, jessie, etc was so bad that I gave up Rpi altogether.  But a couple of years later then I returned with Rpi3B+ and stretch and found things are not that unbearably ugly and slow.  If I gave Rpi1 and wheezy 2/10 marks, I would give Rpi4/buster 7/10.  I use Win10 Win32DskImg1.0 to flash the SD card, everything goes smoothly.  I agree Ubantu used to be good.  But even Google has switched to Debian, so I will follow him - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghHE_kVWXxM.